# Grab Parts of HTML code using Javascript

Tags: javascript

As I'm a noobs on javascript, I need some help to figure out how to grab spesific part of html code using pure javascript.

I wanted to get this part :

> 6LfLgwgTAAAAAFgpAIOgNmfzKi5Ko2ZnNeIE2uLR

**From HTML code below :**

```html
<div id="document-container">
  <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
    <div>
      <iframe src="https://www.example.com/document/api2/anchor?k=6LfLgwgTAAAAAFgpAIOgNmfzKi5Ko2ZnNeIE2uLR&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20170816175713&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=xksmil4x110" title="document widget" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms  allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0">
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <textarea id="g-document-response" name="g-document-response" class="g-document-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; ">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do believe it can be done using *document.getElementById* or *regex*. I think i can do it using PHP, but i have no idea how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Get the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>` element and apply [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979975/218196)

Answer (score 0):

1. give that iframe some unique id to easily access it with javascript
2. do document.getElementById(the id you gave that iframe)
3. read the src attribute from that element
4. parse that k parameter (you could use some URL builder)

Comment: Hi Treibholz, sounds great idea. Could you give me the sample of code, as i don't understand javascript. Really appreciate it.

Comment: check the answer provided by Scath ;) he was a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will get the value of the k param and log it in the console.

```js
const
    iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'),
    url = iframe.getAttribute('src'),
    regex = /k=(.*?)&/,
    regexResult = regex.exec(url);
    
console.log(regexResult[1]);
```

```html
<div id="document-container"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="https://www.example.com/document/api2/anchor?k=6LfLgwgTAAAAAFgpAIOgNmfzKi5Ko2ZnNeIE2uLR&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20170816175713&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=xksmil4x110" title="document widget" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms  allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-document-response" name="g-document-response" class="g-document-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.example.com/document/api2/anchor?k=6LfLgwgTAAAAAFgpAIOgNmfzKi5Ko2ZnNeIE2uLR&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20170816175713&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=xksmil4x110" title="document widget" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms  allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
```

AND JAVASCRIPT:

```
var iframeSrc = document.getElementById("myIframe").src;

var params = parseQuery(iframeSrc.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,''));
function parseQuery ( query ) {
 var Params = new Object ();
 if ( ! query ) return Params; // return empty object
 var Pairs = query.split(/[;&]/);
 for ( var i = 0; i < Pairs.length; i++ ) {
  var KeyVal = Pairs[i].split('=');
  if ( ! KeyVal || KeyVal.length != 2 ) continue;
  var key = unescape( KeyVal[0] );
  var val = unescape( KeyVal[1] );
  val = val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
  Params[key] = val;
  }
  return Params;
  }

  alert(params.k);
```

Here whereas I included id property for your Iframe to map it easily. I got the parser from this [site](http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html).

Let me know if this worked for you. btw, Sorry for the improper indentions.

ALSO Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xx6u9vq8/1/